# Search bar going outside of dropdown in boostrap collapse

Tags: jquery, html, css, flexbox, bootstrap-4

I actually have two problems I need help with:

1. The search bar on smaller screens drops out of the navbar collapse for some reason and I can't figure out why.
2. Awesomplete.js or CSS seems to be overriding the width of the search bar and pushing it to the left side I'm also unsure why.

Here's the jsfiddle if anybody wants to take a crack at it: https://jsfiddle.net/x4vusam1/

```
    .bg-steel {
  /* Permalink - use to edit and share this gradient: http://colorzilla.com/gradient-editor/#09c6f9+0,045de9+100 */
  /* Permalink - use to edit and share this gradient: http://colorzilla.com/gradient-editor/#1e3b70+0,29539b+100 */
  background: purple;
}

.navbar-brand {
  color: white !important;
}

.btn {
  background-color: transparent !important;
}

.navbar-collapse {
  position: relative;
  padding-top: 20px !important;
  max-height: 400px;
}

.navbar-collapse form[role="search"] {
  position: absolute;
  right: 0;
  padding: 0;
  margin: 0;
  z-index: 9;
}

.navbar-collapse form[role="search"] button,
.navbar-collapse form[role="search"] input {
  padding: 8px 12px;
  border-width: 0;
  box-shadow: none;
  outline: none;
}

.navbar-collapse form[role="search"] input {
  padding: 16px 12px;
  font-size: 14pt;
  font-style: italic;
  color: rgb(160, 160, 160);
  box-shadow: none;
}

.navbar-collapse form[role="search"] button[type="reset"] {
  display: none;
}

@media (min-width: 768px) {
  .navbar-collapse {
    padding-top: 0 !important;
    padding-right: 38px !important;
  }
  .navbar-collapse form[role="search"] {
    width: 38px;
  }
  .navbar-collapse form[role="search"] input {
    font-size: 15pt;
    opacity: 0;
    display: none;
  }
  .navbar-collapse form[role="search"].active {
    width: 100% !important;
  }
  .navbar-collapse form[role="search"].active button,
  .navbar-collapse form[role="search"].active input {
    display: table-cell;
    opacity: 1;
  }
}




.awesomplete [hidden] {
    display: none;
}

.awesomplete .visually-hidden {
    position: absolute;
    clip: rect(0, 0, 0, 0);
}

.awesomplete {
    display: inline-block;
    position: relative;
}

.awesomplete > input {
    display: block;
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So I did the following to your code:

1. You don't need `position: absolute` on `.navbar-collapse form[role="search"]` to *place* it to the right in the *navbar* - instead use `justify-content-end` to the `#navbarTogglerDemo02` element.
2. Also add `justify-content-end` class to the `input-group` to *place* the search bar to the right.

See demo below and [`updated fiddle`](https://jsfiddle.net/gavzr5Lj/):

```js
$(function() {
  $('body, .navbar-collapse form[role="search"] button[type="reset"]').on('click keyup', function(event) {
    //console.log(event.currentTarget);
    if (event.which === 27 && $('.navbar-collapse form[role="search"]').hasClass('active') ||
      $(event.currentTarget).attr('type') === 'reset') {
      closeSearch();
    }
  });

  function closeSearch() {
    let $form = $('.navbar-collapse form[role="search"].active');
    $form.find('input').val('');
    $form.removeClass('active');
  }

  $(document).on('click', '.navbar-collapse form[role="search"]:not(.active) button[type="submit"]', function(event) {
    event.preventDefault();
    let $form = $(this).closest('form'),
      $input = $form.find('input');
    $form.addClass('active');
    $input.focus();

  });
});

var aweInput = new Awesomplete(search);
search.addEventListener('awesomplete-select', function(e) {
  var url = e.text.value; // The value associated with the selection
  // Some optional actions:
  e.preventDefault(); // Prevent the URL from appearing in the input box
  e.target.value = e.text.label; // Set the value to the selected label
  aweInput.close(); // close the drop-down
  window.location.href = url;
});
```

```css
.bg-steel {
  /* Permalink - use to edit and share this gradient: http://colorzilla.com/gradient-editor/#09c6f9+0,045de9+100 */
  /* Permalink - use to edit and share this gradient: http://colorzilla.com/gradient-editor/#1e3b70+0,29539b+100 */
  background: purple;
}

.navbar-brand {
  color: white !important;
}

.btn {
  background-color: transparent !important;
}

.navbar-collapse {
  position: relative;
  padding-top: 20px !important;
  max-height: 400px;
}

.navbar-collapse form[role="search"] {
  /* position: absolute; */
  right: 0;
  padding: 0;
  margin: 0;
  z-index: 9;
}

.navbar-collapse form[role="search"] button,
.navbar-collapse form[role="search"] input {
  padding: 8px 12px;
  border-width: 0;
  box-shadow: none;
  outline: none;
}

.navbar-collapse form[role="search"] input {
  padding: 16px 12px;
  font-size: 14pt;
  font-style: italic;
  color: rgb(160, 160, 160);
  box-shadow: none;
}

.navbar-collapse form[role="search"] button[type="reset"] {
  display: none;
}

@media (min-width: 768px) {
  .navbar-collapse {
    padding-top: 0 !important;
    padding-right: 38px !important;
  }
  .navbar-collapse form[role="search"] {
    width: 38px;
  }
  .navbar-collapse form[role="search"] input {
    font-size: 15pt;
    opacity: 0;
    display: none;
  }
  .navbar-collapse form[role="search"].active {
    width: 100% !important;
  }
  .navbar-collapse form[role="search"].active button,
  .navbar-collapse form[role="search"].active input {
    display: table-cell;
    opacity: 1;
  }
}

.awesomplete [hidden] {
  display: none;
}

.awesomplete .visually-hidden {
  position: absolute;
  clip: rect(0, 0, 0, 0);
}

.awesomplete {
  display: inline-block;
  position: relative;
}

.awesomplete>input {
  display: block;
}
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.3.0/css/bootstrap.min.css">
<script type="text/javascript" src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.3.1.slim.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/popper.js/1.14.7/umd/popper.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.3.0/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="https://use.fontawesome.com/releases/v5.7.1/css/all.css">
<script type="text/javascript" src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/awesomplete/1.1.4/awesomplete.js"></script>


<nav class="navbar fixed-top navbar-light bg-steel navbar-expand-md" role="navigation">
  <div class="container">
    <a class="navbar-brand" href="{% url 'main-home' %}">What's The Update?</a>
    <button class="navbar-toggler" type="button" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#navbarTogglerDemo02" aria-controls="navbarTogglerDemo02" aria-expanded="false" aria-label="Toggle navigation">
    <span class="navbar-toggler-icon"></span>
  </button>

    <div class="collapse navbar-collapse justify-content-end" id="navbarTogglerDemo02"> <!-- ADDED class --> 
      <form class="d-flex" role="search">
        <div class="input-group justify-content-end"> <!-- ADDED class --> 
          <input class="form-control awesomplete" id="search" type="text" list="games" placeholder="Search games..." />
          <datalist id="games">
                        
                        <option value="Google.com">Google</option>
                        <option value="Yahoo.com">Yahoo</option>
                        <option value="Wikipedia.org">Wikipedia</option>
                        <option value="Bing.com">Bing</option>
                        
                    </datalist>
          <div class="input-group-append">
            <button type="reset" class="btn">
                            <span class="far fa-times-circle">
       <span class="sr-only">Close</span>
                            </span>
                        </button>
          </div>
          <div class="input-group-append">
            <button type="submit" class="btn btn-light">
                            <span class="fas fa-search">
          <span class="sr-only">Search</span>
                            </span>
                        </button>
          </div>
        </div>
      </form>
    </div>
  </div>
</nav>
```

Comment: Thank you so much. I was struggling to figure out why this was happening. If you don't mind. Do you know why or how the awesomeplete.js is controlling the width of the input field. If you remove the awesomplete.js source on jfiddle the input field changes to the length of the container but when you reinstall the source the input field shrinks.

Comment: Looking at awesomeplete for the first time :D

Answer (score 0):

Take out your content from the form of `class="d-flex"`

```
// form <form class="d-flex" role="search"> // remove the form
     <div class="input-group">
          // your content
     </div>             
//  </form>
```